# IllegalArgumentException: Bound must be positive when using Random.nextInt() method

Tags: java, random, integer

```
//in a method that checks players equipment to change damage and armor values
    //none of these min/max values should spit out anything less than 0
        switch(weapon)
        {
            case"Knife": minDamage = 3; maxDamage = 12; break;
            case"Short Sword": minDamage = 6; maxDamage = 15; break;
            case"Long Sword": minDamage = 8; maxDamage = 20; break;
            case"Battle Axe": minDamage = 14; maxDamage = 28; break;
            case"Death's Blade": minDamage = 20;maxDamage = 60; break;
        }
        //armor

        switch(armor)
        {
            case"Rags": playerArmor = 0; break;
            case"Hide Armor": playerArmor = 5; break;
            case"Leather Armor": playerArmor = 8; break;
            case"Chainmail": playerArmor = 12; break;
            case"Platemail": playerArmor = 20; break;
            case"Death's Armor": playerArmor = 50; break;
        }


        //in a method that handles the combat
        //The problem is somewhere in the logic for the damageDealt integer.
        int damageDealt = rand.nextInt(maxDamage - minDamage + 1)+minDamage;
        int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyDamage - playerArmor);
        if(damageDealt >= 0)
        {
                enemyHealth -=damageDealt;
        }
        else
        {
                damageDealt = 0;
        }
        if(damageTaken>0)
        {
                playerHealth -=damageTaken;
        }
        else
        {
                damageTaken = 0;    
        }
```

So this is just a few lines of code from a Text adventure I'm finishing up. Sometimes I will get this bug that pops up saying IllegalArgumentException: Bound must be positive for java's random() method during the combat.

The first blurb of code is part of a method that handles the players inventory. Take note that every max value for the weapons is larger than the respective min value as they should be. The second blurb of code is part of the combat method. When the player chooses to attack, those lines are run. The damageDealt integer seems to be the issue as far as I can tell.

I'm fairly certain that

```
int damageDealt = rand.nextInt(maxDamage - minDamage + 1)+minDamage;
```

should work and never give an integer value below the minDamage value or even zero for that matter. But, for some reason sometimes it does and the game freaks out and gives that error code.

The issue doesn't occur if I only use maxDamage, but this isn't optimal because then a super high power weapon can do just as little damage as the starting weapon.

If you guys can figure out a solution that would fix my code or even a whole different way to handle randomly choosing a number in an integer range, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Here you sure that the error is comming from `rand.nextInt(maxDamage - minDamage + 1)` and not from `rand.nextInt(enemyDamage - playerArmor)` ?

Comment: Post the stack trace in your question. Unanswerable without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line may be the source of your error:

```
int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyDamage - playerArmor);
```

`Random.nextInt()` will only return a value between 0 (inclusive) and the parameter passed in (exclusive). Therefore, if `enemyDamage - playerArmor` resolves to a negative value, then `nextInt()` will throw an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: so if I moved the playerArmor outside of the () it could fix it? It would change the way the numbers turn out, but honestly it would probably end up making more sense that way.

Comment: @OwenD. Yes, I believe that moving playerArmor outside of `Random.nextInt()` could cause the exception to stop occurring. Also, be sure that `int damageDealt = rand.nextInt(maxDamage - minDamage + 1)+minDamage;` is not evaluating to a negative number, as well. Zero values in `nextInt()` might also cause an issue.

Comment: Think that got it all fixed. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: As a side note, if you are moving playerArmor outside of `nextInt()`, then you may end up with a negative damageTaken instead. You may want to add a check somewhere in your code for a negative damageTaken value and set it to 0. If you decrement the player's health by damageTaken, then when the playerArmor is higher than your `nextInt(enemyDamage)` you will actually be healing the player on hit -- presuming you have not already accounted for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the values passed to `rant.nextInt(int bound)` method.
As the javadoc says, this method

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive) ...

And

> Throws:IllegalArgumentException - if bound is not positive

So, you should pass bound values greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `random.nextInt(x)`, where `x > 0`. To always have a positive value you can use:

```
 random.nextInt(Math.abs(x));
```

`Math.abs(-3)` will output 3.